# How to remove slashes in JSON formatted data in Mongo using Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I am storing the data in the mongo table as JSON format using Nodejs and mongoskin. Mongo automatically adding the slashes in the json formatted data. Then when i retrieving, i can not able to parse the data. Please suggest me, How do i remove the slashes or how do i parse the data?

```
 db.messagetable.find().forEach(printjson)
{
        "_id" : "1861574",
        "MatriId" : "1861574",
        "session" : "{\"messages\":{\"cometchat\":{\"timedifference\":0,\"cometchat_buddytime\":0,\"msgavails\":\"\"}}}",
        "expires" : 1341702134
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here slahses are used to escape the charatcer `"` in your JSON encoded string(not a json object because

```
> JSON.parse("{messages:1}")
SyntaxError: Unexpected token m
    at Object.parse (native)
    at repl:1:7
    at REPLServer.eval (repl.js:80:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:182:12)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:162:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:426:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:603:14)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (readline.js:82:12)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:88:20)
```

so  the keys must be enclosed with `"` to represent a string, but you cannot just put `"` inside the string. To fix that json parsers append the `\`

```
 > JSON.parse("{\"messages\":1}")
{ messages: 1 }
```

so when you parse, just call the `JSON.Parse` on the session string

```
> JSON.parse("{\"messages\":{\"cometchat\":{\"timedifference\":0,\"cometchat_buddytime\":0,\"msgavails\":\"\"}}}")
{ messages: 
   { cometchat: 
      { timedifference: 0,
        cometchat_buddytime: 0,
        msgavails: '' } } }
```

Answer (score 1):

The slashes are not in the string. Slashes are used to represent characters such as `"` because `"` is used as a starting/ending delimiter for strings.

If you were to `console.log` the `session` of that object you printed, it would be printed without the slashes.

There is no slash.